# How to design web service API? Methods? Tools? Outputs?

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, api-design

I am new to web application design. It seems contemporary web applications usually take this form:

- Front-end leverage various JS frameworks to built the UI.
- Then front-end invoke back-end web services with JS to exchange XML or JSON data and update the UI accordingly.
- Back-end is separated into tiers and expose Web service APIs to whatever external.
- Web service APIs also exist for the communication among the back-end tiers.

So the web service APIs should be the critical part to design.

How do we design it? To be specific:

- What data/materials are needed to start the design with?
- What tools can we use? (I heard about some tools to convert XML into classes.)
- And what does the final output of the design look like?

### ADD 1

To be specific, suppose there's requirements like this:

> 1. Customer should be able to upload and delete certain files from the
>    file repository.
> 2. Customer must be authenticated before modifying the files on file repository.

How can I convert it into detailed API spec, and then concrete class definition?

A related link: http://piwik.org/blog/2008/01/how-to-design-an-api-best-practises-concepts-technical-aspects/

### ADD 2  - Regarding RESTful

After reading some books, I came to this:

> RESTful architecture is just *one of the many ways to integrate
> applications*. It leverages Web standards in the hope of making the
> integration *simple and natural*. Resources are identified by URLs,
> manipulated with HTTP methods, and transferred in certain serialization
> form at the convenience of the integrated parties.

Answer (score 2):

To create a Web API (i.e. RESTful service), you need to follow REST principles. I think that this link could give you some hints about the design of RESTful services / Web API: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/03/16/designing-a-web-api/.

To be short, RESTful services should leverage HTTP methods they are designed for:

- method `GET`: return the state of a resource
- method `POST`: perform an action on the resource (creation of an element in a resource list, ...). Be careful not to use an action name within URLs (something like `/elements/some-action-name`) because it's not RESTful.
- method `PUT`: update the complete state of a resource
- method `PATCH`: update partially the state of a resource
- method `DELETE`: delete a resource

You need also to be aware that they can apply at different levels, so methods won't do the same things:

- a list resource (for example, path `/elements`)
- an element resource (for example, path `/elements/{elementid}`)

Other important things you must consider are:

- To use status codes to tell the client if the request is sucessful (2xx family), fails because of the client (4xx family) or of the server (5xx family)
- To leverage HTTP headers. For example, the header `Content-Type` for the type of content used (application/json for JSON for example) and `Accept` for content negotiation if needed...

Otherwise there are some formats like [Swagger](http://swagger.io/) and [RAML](http://raml.org/) you can leverage to craft your Web API. A tool like [Restlet Studio](http://studio.restlet.com/) could a good help to create the structure of your REST service online, get the corresponding Swagger and RAML contents, and even generate server skeletons or client SDKs. You can notice that this tool only follows REST principles...

Regarding security, you need to leverage the `Authorization` header. There are several strategies:

- Basic one. The username / password are encoded with Base64 and sent in the header.
- Token-based one. You could have a look at this link for more details: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/
- OAuth2. See this link: http://www.bubblecode.net/en/2013/03/10/understanding-oauth2/.

Regarding file upload, you can leverage multipart contents. See this link: http://restlet.com/blog/2015/10/27/implementing-file-upload-with-restlet-framework/. We use the Restlet framework but you might pick up some generic hints...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: I think that **method POST: execute an action** goes against REST principles. REST is about resources, not actions.

Comment: Yes "execute an action" can be perhaps a bit ambiguous. I agree with you if you use an action name in the URL, it's not RESTful. Perhaps saying "perform an action on the resource" would be better... The HTTP specification uses the word "action" (see http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.5) in the POST method section.

Comment: I updated my answer. Does it seem clearer to you? Thanks!

Comment: I've some doubts yet. I think that POST is only for **create** resources (and in some cases update them if you can't use PUT). If you want to perform an action over the resource you have to consider the acion a resource itself. POST /actions?resourceid=1

Comment: I think slightly different opinions can always exist for the HTTP methods semantics.  But I think the general idea is: *to let the conventional HTTP methods imply the action, and the URL to represent subject*.

Comment: @thierrytemplier Is RESTful suitable for all/most scenarios? Is there any particular pre-requisites that RESTful methodology can be adopted?

Comment: @thierrytemplier After reading more, I came to this: the ultimate goal of REST (REpresentational State Transfer) is *to transfer the state of resource*. To achieve that, we need a way *to identify resource* (e.g. URL), a way *to represent resource* (e.g. JSON, XML, etc.), a way *to manipulate it* (HTTP methods) and a way *to transfer it* (e.g. HTTP protocol).  But that's just for the Web scenario. REST is not just limited to HTTP protocols.

Comment: Well, after one night's sleep, I feel there's too much *bluff* around web API. The ultimate goal is nothing but to `communicate between 2 distributed pieces of code`. Data need to be serialized for wire transmission and de-serialized upon receiving. All the HTTP infrastructure (URL, HTTP methods, headers, etc.) are JUST for locating the 2 pieces of code and providing instructions on manipulating the data.

Comment: RESTful architecture is just *one of the many ways to integrate applications*. It leverages Web standards in the hope of making the integration *simple and natural*. Resources are identified by URLs, manipulated with HTTP methods, and transferred in many serialization forms.

Comment: @smwikipedia I think you understand well what REST is! ;-) The aim is to use things they are made for in HTTP!

Comment: @smwikipedia I could also mention hypermedia if you want to make it "browsable". I mean someone would be able to discover what is possible to use without any documentation (the service would be self-descriptive). See this link for more details: http://sookocheff.com/post/api/on-choosing-a-hypermedia-format/

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion the concept of a Rest-full API is a little blurry, I would advise you to take a look at this article http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html

Not many public rest-full api's actually achive the discussed level 3. The general idea it to model your api around the "resources" your application deals in and respect the proper http verbs.

As for tools I kinda like https://apiary.io/ it helps you build an API and can provide mock responses as well